# scikit-learn Ridge Regression UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm just a beginner and I'm trying to implement polynomial regression in scikit-learn. The usual regression without regularization works fine

```
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression(copy_X=True)
X = np.array(time_list[0:24]).reshape(24,1)
for i in range(2,10):
   X=np.append(X, X**i, 1)
Y = np.array(tempm_list[0:24]).reshape(24,1)

regr.fit(X, Y)
```

but when I try to implement Ridge regression in exactly the same way, I get the following error:

```
regularized_regr=linear_model.Ridge(alpha =1, copy_X=True)
regularized_regr.fit(X,Y)


File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/ridge.py", line 449,    in fit
return super(Ridge, self).fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/ridge.py", line 338, in fit
solver=self.solver)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/ridge.py", line 294, in ridge_regression
coef = safe_sparse_dot(X.T, dual_coef, dense_output=True).T
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dual_coef' referenced before assignment
```

Thanks

Comment: [This commit](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/23fb79887e01dbe1f387c87518b0f445dc5e4fa9) suggests it is a bug in scikit.  Not sure if the fix is in a released version or not.  You could try updating your scikit install.

Comment: As @BrenBarn says, this may be a bug that is fixed in the bleeding edge version of scikit-learn. In the meanwhile, could you try a higher `alpha`? I will calculate a suggestion for you below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suggestion: Decrease your polynomial degree to e.g. <= 5. Anything above will enter the realm of overfitting given your number of samples

Second suggestion: Upgrade Scikit learn to the bleeding edge github version, this seems to be a bug related to an exception raised because your matrix is singular.

If you cannot upgrade scikit learn, try using a stronger regularization:

```
import numpy as np
_, S, _ = np.linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False)
s = S[0]

alpha = 1.2 * s  # you may vary this fraction between 0.1 and larger

regularized_regr=linear_model.Ridge(alpha=alpha)
regularized_regr.fit(X,Y)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone - I did actually try to upgrade to the latest bleeding edge github version earlier, but had some errors with the install:
    clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-  command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

But anyway, although I was intentionally ridiculously overfitting, reducing the polynomial degree to 5 fixes the error. Thanks!!

Comment: Btw., the bleeding edge version also has `sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures` for polynomial regression.